# Django: is there an assertNumQueries method which can run the assertion as a subtest?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'd like to run a block of code and ensure the amount of queries generated is in check, however, I want the test code to proceed if this check fails.

Pseudo-code:

```
def assertNumQueriesSubTest(func, expected_number):
    with self.countNumQueries as query_count:
        func()

        with self.subTest('query check'):
             self.assertEqual(queries_count, expected_number)
```

With the classic `assertNumQueries`, the test code stops if the query count does not match the expected value, however, this prevents me from debugging tests properly, since the reason for which the query count changed may not be obvious, so I would like to know if at least the behavior matches is still the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [solution for OpenWISP which executes the assertions in a subtest](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-utils/commit/235b0e18a0c9cc1de4dedd187ced9cb69f7b8497), it's documented here: [openwisp_utils.tests.AssertNumQueriesSubTestMixin](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-utils#openwisp-utils-tests-assertnumqueriessubtestmixin).